# A question about Gromov's proof of a "more effective version of the main theorem"

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

In the paper *"Groups of polynomial growth and expanding maps"* Gromov proves the following "effective version of the main theorem"

> For any positive integers $d$ and $k$, there exists positive integers $R$, $N$ and $q$ with the following properties. If a group $\Gamma$ with a fixed system of generators satisfies the inequality $|B(r)|\leq kr^d$ for $r=1,2,\cdots, R$, then $\Gamma$ contains a nilpotent subgroup $\Gamma'$ of index at most $q$ and whose degree of nilpotency is at most $N$

He goes on to state the following definition

> Let $\Delta$ and $\Gamma^i$, $i=1,2,\cdots,$ be a system of groups endowed with a fixed system of generators. We say that the sequence $(\Gamma^i)$ converges to $\Delta$ if there is a sequence of balls $B_i=B(r_i)\subset \Delta$ with $r_i\rightarrow\infty$ for $i\rightarrow\infty$ and a sequence of bijective maps $f$ of each ball $B_i$ onto the $r_i$ ball in $\Gamma^i$ centered at the identity such that $f(\delta_1\delta_2^{-1})=f(\delta_1)f(\delta_2)^{-1}$ for any two elements $\delta_1,\delta_2$ in $\Delta$ satisfiying $||\delta_1||+||\delta_2||\leq r_i$

My question is about this statement

> An arbitrary sequence of groups $\Gamma^i$ each with $k$ given generators, always has a convergent subsequence.

Why? How's this $\Delta$ constructed?

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is the “space of marked groups”.

Comment: If $X$ is a set, $2^X$ is compact in the product topology. If $G$ is a group, the set $N(G)$ of normal subgroups of $G$ is closed in $2^G$, hence compact. Then the space of marked groups on $k$ generators can just be identified to $N(F_k)$ and thus is compact.

Comment: How is $2^X$ being endowed with the product topology (is it identified with $\prod_{a\in X}\{0,1\}$)? What is the topology on the space of marked groups?

Comment: @AName: now that you have the keyword, a simple Google search should give you many references with further details.  For instance, here is one: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401042v2 .